# Announcement list & web part in publishing site

Tags: publishing-site, team-sites

I know that i should activate team collab. features to be able to use OOB announcement list & web part. I wonder if there is another way without activating the team collab. features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create an accouncements list on any site using "Site Action" | "More Options" and choose "Announcements"

Once the announcements list is created you can insert the list web part for it on any page.

If the site doesn't have the announcements list you can either active the visible `Team Collaboration Lists` feature or the hidden `announcementslist` feature (`Enable-SPFeature
announcementslist
-url URL_OF_SITE`)

Comment: On a publishing site (that has team collab feature not enabled) there is no Announcements option on "Site Action" | "More Options"

Comment: Sorry answer updated